How is the zIndex order of iOS Mapkit overlays determined?
I'm struggling to understand the behavior of MKMapView and it's underlying components. How does MKMapView determine the order of rendering of MKOverlays? In other words, how can I manipulate this order for example to draw a blue circle on top of a red box?
At first a logical reasoning would be the order of items in the interal overlays array, however this is debunked in the documentation.
Now I'm inclined to believe this is based by when an item is added to the map, everything that's added later wil be on top of the rest. But this does not seem to be documented anywhere and it makes things more difficult when you manually want to change it.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
